# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. with valid address

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am developing a software which send email after the user pressed a button.
I encounter some issues with these emails: they **sometimes** raise this exception: `The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`. I emphasise on **sometimes** because they actually works sometimes.

Surprising thing is that the mail addresses are actually correctly formatted: they all look like `blahblah@domain.com` or `Blah Blah <blahblah@domain.com>`. This even happens with some of my company's mails, which - of course - are valid. I even checked all the addresses with this regex and they **all** passed: `^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$`.

Here are the steps my software is going through:

1. **Add the main address**:

   ```
   var mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("logistics@company.com", "company logistics department"), new MailAddress(address));
   ```

Here the `address` is valid since the software did send an email to this address prior to this step.

2. **In a loop I add the CCs addresses**:

   ```
   mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress(email));
   ```

Here I applied a null/empty check so I am not adding any empty mail address.

3. **And finally I add myself in BCC address**:

   ```
   mail.Bcc.Add("my@company.com");
   ```

Is there any issue in the way I'm doing this ?

Are there some known issues (additionnaly random ones) about the C# .NET mail class?

Is there a limit on the maximum amount of To / CC / Bcc addresses this class can handle ?

EDIT: i'm using System.Net.Mail classes